# Can users rate a restaurant by using google places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am able to get restaurants list, timings, rating and displaying them in my Android application by using Google places API.  This is API

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=13.0104611,80.2086226&
radius=10000&types=cafe|restaurant&hasNextPage=true&nextPage()=true&sensor=false&key=MY_API_KEY

As per my client requirement,  Users should be able to give rating to a specific restaurant from my application, this restaurant got from above Googel API.

Kindly tell me whether possible or not giving rating to a restaurant from above API .  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro), using the Google Places API Web Service, the following place requests are available:

> - **Place Searches** return a list of places based on a user's location or search string.
> - **Place Details** requests return more detailed information about a specific Place, including user reviews.
> - **Place Add** allow you to supplement the data in Google's Places database with data from your application.
> - **Place Photos** gives you access to the millions of Place related photos stored in Google's Place database.
> - **Place Autocomplete** can be used to automatically fill in the name and/or address of a place as you type.
> - **Query Autocomplete** can be used to provide a query prediction service for text-based geographic searches, by returning suggested queries as you type.

The only request that allows to put data is Place Add, but according to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) it adds a place that is available immediately in Nearby Searches initiated by your application and also enters a moderation queue to be considered for Google Maps.

So the answer is that for the time being it's not possible to add reviews to Places using the Google Places API Web Service.

Comment: Thanks for your response antonio.

Comment: The [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).